# Discord.js | How to stop awaitReactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have giveaway embed with a reaction. After 10000 ms the giveaway ends and everything functions right. Now I want to stop the giveaway before 10000ms, because I added a 'giveaway end' command. And I have another question, if I have less reactions (without bot) than winners something like this happens: @x, @y, @z,,,,,(3 reactions and 7 winners). Can I cut that out?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.channels.get(giveawayChannelid).fetchMessage(messageID)
      .then(message => {  
      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id != bot.user.id;
      };
      
      message.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
      .catch(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        winnersEnd=reaction.users.filter((user) => !user.bot).random(winners);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a global var, setting true when giveaways start, setting false when stop, and condition to lock, maybe in the filter callback ?.
also you should use a max setting in the option of message awaitReaction

Comment: it doesnt work first I cant have a maximum because infinty dudes can react to win, second when I lock it in the filter with true or false the giveaway wont be end before time is zero and no reactions while that will be detected

Comment: Well, if i understand correctly, you want the giveaways to stop 10s later OR when you ask it by an another function.
At the end, you want to get the list of reaction that happen in between start and stop.
Using a filter with a external var should work ? if you just want to detect the reaction comming after stop but, want to do something else with them, dont use the var in the filter but save it as a property of the collected react, and use it later in a if block.
Is it helping you ?